# Doctrine 2 namespace issue

Tags: namespaces, doctrine-orm

I'm using Zend Framework 1 with the Bisna library to integrate Doctrine 2. I generated my Entities from my database model with the Doctrine 2 CLI. This is all working fine, except for the setter methods for associated records. The argument they accept must be of a specific namespace (`\Category` here).

```
class Article
{
    public function setCategory(\Category $category = null) {
        $this->category = $category;
        return $this;
    }
}
```

However, when I do this:

```
$article    = $this->em->getRepository('\Application\Entity\Article')->find(1);

$category   = new \Application\Entity\Category();
$category->SetName('New Category');

$article->setCategory($category);
```

I get the following fatal error: `Argument 1 passed to Application\Entity\CategoryField::setCategory() must be an instance of Category, instance of Application\Entity\Category given`.

When I change the setter method to accept `\Application\Entity\Category` objects, it's working of course. Should I do this for every generated method, or are there other options? This is the first time I'm using namespaces, so it might be something simple.

Answer (score 0):

You can always add this to the top of your class file: `use \Application\Entity\Category;` and then simply reference it later like so: `public function setCategory(Category $category = null)`

Check out: http://php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.importing.php for more info about `use`

Otherwise you would have to reference the full namespace otherwise your application does not know that `\Category` is a reference to `\Application\Entity\Category`